# How to use javascript in codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, methods, controller, protected

**js_class.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class js_class extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper(array( 'form', 'url' ));
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->load->library('pagination');


    }


    public function index() {
        $data['library_src'] = $this->jquery->script();
        $data['click'] = $this->jquery->_click('#click', "alert('Hello! You Click the button');");


        $this->load->view('js_class_view', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

---

**config.php**

```
$config['javascript_location'] = 'http://localhost/test/assets/js/jquery.min.js';
```

When I compiled the code an error occurred, which says a call to protected method `CI_jquery::_click()`. Please help me if you have faced and solved such problem

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->jquery->click`?

Comment: In CI_jquery there is _click () function ,but it is protected.,since it is system file I think making it public is not the way.is the $config ['javascript_location'] correct

Answer (score 0):

Please Correct this code

$data['click'] = $this->jquery->_click('#click', "alert('Hello! You Click the button')");

to remove ";" on this "alert('Hello! You Click the button');" code